# proper use of SSL certificate with Soup in javascript

Tags: javascript, ssl, certificate, gjs, cacerts

I would like to ask how to properly use Soup in gnome-shell extension with a certificate on the client site.

The snippet of my code looks like this:

```
const Soup = imports.gi.Soup;
const GObject = imports.gi.GObject;
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;

const TlsDatabase = GObject.registerClass({
    Implements: [Gio.TlsFileDatabase],
    Properties: {
        'anchors': GObject.ParamSpec.override('anchors', Gio.TlsFileDatabase),
    },
}, class TlsDatabase extends Gio.TlsDatabase {});


let session = Soup.Session.new();
session.ssl_strict = true;
session.tls_database = new TlsDatabase({anchors: "path.pem"});;
```

- After the request, I always get Gio.TlsCertificateFlags.GENERIC_ERROR in the answer.
- Without setting session.tls_database, the error code is 3 and I did not find what does means. So something is happening and I suspect the TlsDatabase is not OK.
- Using `session.ssl_strict = false`, it works and I got my answer, but I would like to have a secure connection.
- Certificate and server site are OK, I have verified it with curl `curl --ssl --cacert path.pem ...`. It works.

Edited:

- This error is shown: `g_tls_database_verify_chain: assertion 'G_TLS_DATABASE_GET_CLASS (self)->verify_chain' failed`

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to implement [`vfunc_verify_chain()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/gio20%7E2.66p/gio.tlsdatabase#vfunc-verify_chain) in your class. (It's not clear to me whether `Gio.TlsDatabase` provides no default implementation of this virtual function, or it does and this is a bug.)